# selecting and comparing two MySQL tables entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

What I have is two databases: Users_1, Users_2.

Users_1 has fields: name (name and surname inside and some number in brackets like: tom hanks (12345) ) and address (inside like: street house_number flat_number).
i need to confirm the name/surname and the full address is the same, and then for a match, append the number in brackets from Users_1 to a new column in Users_2.

So far I managed to write SQL query for extracting numbers from brackets which is going to get in handy when transferring the number to a matched row in Users_2:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(substr(name,instr(name,"(") + 1), ')', 1) as temp from Users_1;
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you made a mistake when speaking of "two databases" ? I suppose you meant "Two tables" ?

Comment: to me it looks like bad design ... you should have the user identifier in a separate column NOT concatenated in the `name` column

Comment: my bad, yes, there are two tables.

Comment: information for Users_1 comes from a source. I can redo it the way I like (keeping in mind this should be automated as much as possible, so that people managing records shoudn't mess with the db directly)